# Determine the joint pmf of $X$ and $Y$

Tags: probability, proof-verification

> Two distinct coins, $A$ and $B$, are tossed three times. $A$ is fair coin, that is, $P(\textrm{heads}) = P(\textrm{tails}) = 1/2$. $B$ is not a fair coin, with, $P(\textrm{heads}) = 1/4$ and $P(\textrm{tails}) = 3/4$. Let $X$ be the $r.v.$ that denotes the number of heads from $A$, and $Y$ be the $r.v.$ that denotes the number of heads from $B$.
>
> Determine the join pmf of $X$ and $Y$.

My reasoning:

Clearly these are two random variables with binomial distributions.Let $Z = X + Y$. Then $Z \sim \textrm{Binom}(n = 3, p= \frac{0.5 + 0.25}{2} = 0.375)$

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is wrong. The question is asking for the joint pmf, which, since $X,Y$ are independent, is just a product of the individual pmf's.

To find such a thing, you should be looking at $Z=(X,Y)$, not $Z=X+Y$, which is a convolution...

Comment: There is a theorem that says that you cannot find the joint pmf from the marginal pmfs. So what is going on?

Comment: @VictorS.: I'm not sure which theorem you're talking about, but if $X$ and $Y$ are independent (as we have every reason to believe), then the joint PMF of $X$ and $Y$ is the product of the marginal PMFs.  This is an immediate consequence of their independence.  If the variables are not independent, then it is true that the joint PMF cannot be so determined, but there's nothing here to suggest that's the case.

Comment: Casella & Berger, $\textit{Statistical Inference}$, $p. 144$. You can get the book on libgen. It says: 

The marginal distributions of $ X $ and $ Y $, described by the marginal pmfs $ f_X(x) $ and $ f_Y(y) $ do not completely descrive the joint distribution of $ X $ and $ Y $. There are many different joint distributions that have the same marginal distributions. Thus, it is hopeless to try to determine the joint pmf $ f_{XY}(x y) $ from knowledge of only the marginal pmfs.

Comment: @BrianTung would you mind giving me a textbook reference that says I can just multiply the marginal pmfs when they are independent?

Comment: @VictorS. As Brian wrote, your quote applies *generally*, but we have the additional fact of $X,Y$ being independent. That changes everything. you can see that [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution#Joint_distribution_for_independent_variables) even defines independence that way.

Comment: @gt6989b the same textbook says, p. 152: $X$ and $Y$ are called independent random variables if, for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}, f(x, y) = f_X(x)f_X(y)$. Notice the relationship is $\Rightarrow$, not $\Leftrightarrow$. If I can just multiply the pmfs to obtain the joint pmf then the random variables are independent, it doesn't say the inverse.

Comment: @VictorS. - that p.152 is the _definition_ of "independent", so it is $\iff$.  this is like say, an integer is _even_ if it is a multiple of $2$.  the unspoken direction "if an integer is even then it is a multiple of $2$" is implied since this is a definition.